# get_or_create object created or found?

Tags: django

I want to use get_or_create in some view and I want to know if it is made or found?

One of the lines looks like this:

```
source,p = Source.objects.get_or_create(name="Website")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). An example from official documentation;

```
obj, created = Person.objects.get_or_create(
    first_name='John',
    last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'birthday': date(1940, 10, 9)},
)
```

> If an object is found, get_or_create() returns a tuple of that object and False.

Then check `created` variable;

```
In [15]: created
Out[15]: False 
# so, `get_or_create()` didn't create an object.
```

Answer (score 1):

get_or_create always return tuple.
First value is object
And second is Boolean , if second value is True it means object has created otherwise object already exists.